# how can i create a tag for each word present in widget text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tags, text-widget

I'd like to create a tag for each word in my text widget.

This is my starting code.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class text_editor(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, entry_initial_value='...'):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        indexes = [0, 1]
        self.columnconfigure(indexes, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(indexes, weight=1)

        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        my_text = "one one\ntwo two\nthree three"
        self.text.insert('1.0', my_text)
        #row.char
        self.text.grid(column=0, row=0)


class App(tk.Tk):
    # costruttore
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure the root window
        self.title('My App')
        self.geometry('300x50')
        c = text_editor(self)
        c.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Is there an easy way to handle this problem or is the only way to handle the coordinates of each word, specifying for each word the row it belongs to and the starting and ending index?

p.s.
are there any other ways to select the characters that belong to the tag other than the coordinate system of the raw.char type?
like in this example

```py
text.tag_add('highlightline', '5.0', '6.0')
```

Comment: How do you define "word" in this context? In the sentence "one two. three" is "two" a word, or is "two." a word?

Comment: "two" Is a word.